# Приходит пустой Post запрос AJAX + Spring Boot

Tags: json, ajax, spring, mvc

На фронт-енд стороне есть такой код:

```
$("#add_button").click(function() {
    console.log("Кнопка была нажата");
    var genre = {
        name: $("#genre_name").val(),
        description: $("#genre_desc").val()
    };
            
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/save_genre",
    data: JSON.stringify(genre),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response) {
        // Обработка успешного ответа
        console.log("Жанр успешно создан:", response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // Обработка ошибки
        console.error("Произошла ошибка при создании жанра:", error);
    }
});
```

В нём мы по нажатю кнопки считываем данные с двух форм, создаём объект, сериализуем его в JSON-формат и отправляем POST запрос на сервер по URL "/save_genre".

В свою очередь на серверной стороне принимаем и записываем в базу данных:

```
@RestController
public class AddGenreRestController {

    @Autowired
    private GenreRepository GenreRepository;

    @PostMapping("/save_genre")
    public Genres addGenre(@RequestBody Genres genre) {
        System.out.println("Genre = " + genre.GetName());
        return GenreRepository.save(genre);
    }
}
```

В ответ на строчку: `System.out.println("Genre = " + genre.GetName());` в консоль выводится значение `Genre = null`. В таблице создаётся новая запись, однако в полях также стоит значение `NULL`.

Почему это происходит и как исправить?